# Losing hues and other styles when updating to Angular Material 1.1.1

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material

Past week I updated my project from Angular Material 1.0.8 to Angular Material 1.1.1.

After this update, I got the following issues related to styling:

- *hues* aren't working. For example: `md-background hue-1`. Some components like `md-toolbar` had a default background and now there's no style applied at all.
- Components like `md-chip` or `md-select` are styled wrongly. `md-select` gets a transparent background, and `md-chips` have less styling than expected:

[image: md-select]

[image: md-chips]

I've no custom styles in my own stylesheet and I can't figure out what's happening (same app with Angular Material 1.0.8 had no issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, the following line has solved the issue during configuration phase:

```
$mdThemingProvider.generateThemesOnDemand(false);
```

I'm not sure about why this solves the problem, but at least I understand that this mimics the behavior in previous releases of Angular Material.